# Java error: Cannot find symbol (acm)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, acm-java-libraries

well,i am trying to create a program that allocates 10000 rational objects without saving any of them
in variables so that they all become garbage. After that i have to measure the
amount of free memory before and after garbage collection and use the difference to
report how many bytes were freed. 
So far, i have created two .java file. The Rational.java and gc.java.
I create the constructor  Rational so i can "call" it in my void run method of the gc.java files.
The constructor creates a new rational object with the value x/y.

**BUT,i get the error:** Java error: cannot find symbol

symbol method gcd(Math.abs(x),Math.abs(y));

location class Rational

1 error

Here is my TWO JAVA FILES:

**RATIONAL.java**

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Rational {

    public Rational(int x,int y) {

        int g = gcd(Math.abs(x),Math.abs(y));
        int num;
        int den;
        num = x/g;
        den = Math.abs(y)/g;
        if (y<0) {
            num = -num;
        }
    }
}
```

**AND GC.java**

```
import acm.program.*;


public  class gc extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {

        println("Allocating 10000 objects");

        for(int i = 0;i<10000;i++) {
            new Rational(i+1,i+2);
        }

        Runtime myTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long a = myTime.freeMemory();
        println(a);
        myTime.gc();
        long b = myTime.freeMemory();
        println(b);
        println((a-b));
    }
}
```

I can't find were my mistake is,so i can fix it. Your help would be appreciated

problem is,according to the compiler here: int g = gcd(Math.abs(x),Math.abs(y));

EDIT: WORKED!! Just created the gcd method right!

Comment: SO is becoming a `cc` (crowd compiler)

Comment: sorry,i didnt understand you @OlegMikheev

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because you don't have any method called `gcd`! Perhaps you're supposed to write one?

Comment: how can i create the gcd? is it needed? or is  an easier way to do it?

Comment: @HpdsbuΖt You should ask your instructor. These are the basics you should be covering in class.

Comment: You need to write the method `public int gcd(int x, int y)`.  Because it doesn't exist, Java is throwing that compiler error.

Comment: got that. Can you give me a hint,on what to put into the gcd method?

Comment: @HpdsbuΖt I'd try the binary method.